# Is it good practice for a Jetpack ViewModel to implement an interface?

Tags: android, interface, viewmodel, android-jetpack, dagger

In a project every Jetpack Viewmodel implements an interface. For example:

```
interface ExamReportViewModel : ActionSource<ExamReportViewModel.Action>,
    ExamExamineeListItem.Listener {

    val examReportId: StateFlow<String?>
    val examReportHeader: StateFlow<ExamReportHeader?>
    val examExamineeList: StateFlow<List<ExamExamineeListItem>>
    val isHeaderExpanded: StateFlow<Boolean>

    fun setExamReportId(id: String)
    fun toggleHeaderExpanded()
    fun navigateToExtraordinaryEvent()

    sealed class Action {
        data class ToIdentificationDialog(val examReportId: String, val examineeId: String) : Action()
        data class ToEvaluation(val exam: Exam) : Action()
        object ToExtraordinaryEvent : Action()
    }
}
```

An actual implementation:

```
class ExamReportViewModelImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val examReportInteractor: ExamReportInteractor,
    private val errorDelegate: ErrorDelegate,
) : BaseViewModel(), ExamReportViewModel
```

Does this make sense? What would be the cons and pros?
Cons:

1. The chances that the same view model requires 2 different implementations are close to 0
2. we can hide the MutableStateFlow implementation in a private field inside the viewmodel and just us .asStateFlow() to convert it to a non mutable one
3. it needs to be declared
4. they are testable with and without the interface
5. it makes injecting with dagger hilt complicated, because there is a BaseFragment which is based on generics

Are there any pros?

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : Any, B : ViewDataBinding>(
        open val contentViewId: Int,
    ) : DaggerFragment() {
    
        @Inject
        lateinit var viewModel: T
    }
class ExamReportFragment :
        BaseFragment<ExamReportViewModel, FragmentExamReportBinding>(R.layout.fragment_exam_report) {
}
```

With this approach I was not able to use the

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<TasksViewModel>()
```

extension. I don't know if it's possible or if it makes sense.

Comment: One potential pro is if you wanted to test your `Fragment` in isolation with a fake view model implementation, in which you could manually emit values into flows. It's not my testing approach, but I can imagine someone doing it depending on their needs.

Comment: Okey, but I can also fake the dependencies of the view model, instead of faking the viewmodel itself.